# Converting Constructor doesn't accept a Braced List

Tags: c++, constructor, braces, list-initialization

So while I was messing with constructors I made this code:

```
class super
{
public:
int duper, duperer;

friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, super&);
friend super operator+ (super& uno, super& dos);
friend int main();
super() {};
super(int);
super(int, int);
};

ostream& operator << (ostream& out, super& Sout)
{
    cout << "The " << Sout.duper << " and the " << Sout.duperer << " are super!" << endl;
    return out;
}

super operator+ (super& uno, super& dos)
{
    return { uno.duper + dos.duper , uno.duperer + dos.duperer };
}


super::super(int duper) : duper(duper) {};
super::super(int dupster, int pupster) : duper(pupster), duperer(dupster)     {};

int main()
{

super Supper = { -1, 0 }, Copper(1, 1);
Supper = super(3, 3) + Copper;
cout << Supper << "!!!\n";
}
```

It all works properly and the initializer_list is converted to the object of my type every time. However, when I do this (change the constructor for the braced list in the main):

```
class super
{
public:
int duper, duperer;

friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, super&);
friend super operator+ (super& uno, super& dos);
friend int main();
super() {};
super(int);
super(int, int);
};

ostream& operator << (ostream& out, super& Sout)
{
    cout << "The " << Sout.duper << " and the " << Sout.duperer << " are super!" << endl;
    return out;
}

super operator+ (super& uno, super& dos)
{
    return { uno.duper + dos.duper , uno.duperer + dos.duperer };
}


super::super(int duper) : duper(duper) {};
super::super(int dupster, int pupster) : duper(pupster), duperer(dupster)     {};

int main()
{

super Supper = { -1, 0 }, Copper(1, 1);
Supper = {3, 3} + Copper;
cout << Supper << "!!!\n";
}
```

...the code doesn't compile. Why doesn't braced list get converted to an object this time?

Thank you very much and please don't get mad over the names I used here. I just wanted to make sure everything is confusing enough.

Comment: "It all works properly" -- no it doesn't. If your compiler actually compiled what you describe as "works properly" then it must be a bug in your compiler. Temporary values do not bind to mutable references.  This has nothing to do with your constructor, whatsoever. Your `operator+` is broken. In both chunks of code you showed. The `operator+` must take `const` references as parameters, not mutable ones, which will not bind to temporary values.

Comment: MSVC does indeed compile this code, but at least gives a warning message. gcc and clang both barf.

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].